# Is there a way to specify an empty key in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, relational-database, rdbms

If I understand this correctly then specifying an empty key on a table will ensure that it will only contain zero or exactly one row.

Is it possible to specify an empty key in SQL?

Comment: What RDBMS are you working with, and what is your goal? I suspect most will report an error with a zero-length index (if that is what you mean).

Comment: (a quick test of MySQL verifies that - index length cannot be 0)

Comment: We use Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I think this would come in handy in situations where I want to store exactly one value in a table. For instance, global application settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your primary key computed:

```
CREATE TABLE T 
(   
        ID AS 1,
        SomeField VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT PK_T_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT T (SomeField) VALUES ('Test');
INSERT T (SomeField) VALUES ('Test2');
```

The first insert will work, but the second will throw the error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_T_ID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.T'. The duplicate key value is (1).

This will ensure your table contains 0 or 1 rows.

Comment: Good answer. I would make one tiny amendment. ID is not the primary key of this table. The only candidate key is () - the empty set. So in the interests of clarity and accuracy it would be better to use the UNIQUE key constraint in place of PRIMARY KEY even though they achieve the same thing in practice.

Comment: @GarethD -- interesting approach to this question.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question, "Is it possible to specify an empty key in SQL" : no.

Just like it is impossible to define tables with no columns (not the same issue, but tangential).

Tricks and hacks like in GarethD's answer will be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Having an empty key is equivalent to having at most one tuple. (At most one value associated with key value {}.)

There are lots of restrictions on CHECK. In SQL Server one could write a function

```
CREATE TABLE T (c int);
GO
CREATE FUNCTION f()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @retval int
   SELECT @retval = COUNT(*) FROM T
   RETURN @retval
END;
GO
ALTER TABLE T
ADD CONSTRAINT emptyKey CHECK (dbo.f() <= 1 );
GO
```

INSERT INTO T (c) VALUES (1),(2)

The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "emptyKey". The conflict occurred in database "db_3_2c694d", table "dbo.T".: INSERT INTO T (c) VALUES (1),(2)

It isn't a problem for this particular constraint that CHECKs are not supported on DELETE. (However, there may be other issues with functions in constraints where this is not treated soundly.)

Comment: This is a nice idea, but a check constraint can't contain an aggregate function.